# "Pay the full amount" or "pay the whole amount"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Can you please tell me if I need to use *full* or *whole* in the context below?

> I would like to pay the **full** amount instead of breaking it down into installments.
>
> I would like to pay the **whole** amount instead of breaking it down into installments.

If both are perfectly natural, which one in your experience is used more commonly?

Comment: The speaker pays the whole/full amount eventually in any case. It would be more usual to say "I would like to pay the full/whole amount **now** instead of by installments."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The whole amount* and *the full amount* mean the same in this context. Both are acceptable. The frequency of the usage of these can be viewed using the [google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+full+amount%2C+the+whole+amount&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). I wouldn't read too much into the ups and downs of the graph however. Examples of either can be easily found.

Note: the use of "breaking it down into" appears to be redundant since **instalment** (US spelling: *installment*) already means: *a sum of money due as one of several equal payments for something, spread over an agreed period of time*.